# Sum of sub-bars on top of stacked bars in tikz

Tags: pgfplots

I want to be able to display the sum of the values on top of the bars. Below is my code and under that, an illustrated image that displays the values I want to show. Can this be done?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,
    bar width=15pt,
    ymin=0,
    nodes near coords,
    %enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Seconds (s)},
    symbolic x coords={t1, t2, t3, t4},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={rotate=41,anchor=east},
    ]
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(t1, 70) (t2, 94) (t3, 70) (t4, 70)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(t1, 43) (t2, 43) (t3, 61) (t4, 71)};
\legend{\strut d1,\strut  d2,\strut  d3}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/qPaYiKD.jpg]
\n

**Edit:**

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
```

makes it so that the values reside inside the bars. Without it, a sum of values are stacked on top of the bars. I do however want the sum at the top, then the value of each bar displayed inside of them, just as in the illustration.